# How to get the string after a particular string + slash in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a URL string like so:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/code/12345/id/6789
```

I’d like to extract the text after “code” (1234) and “id” (6789) separately.

Comment: Solution on following SO page and is marked as correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: @Spangle It's not URL params though but the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure your url is in this format only i.e. first key and then value. You can create a simple function like this:

```js
function getParamFromUrl(url, key){
  const splitUrl = url.split('/')
  return splitUrl[splitUrl.indexOf(key) + 1]
}

const url = 'http://www.somedomain.com/code/12345/id/6789'
const valueOfCode = getParamFromUrl(url, 'code') // 12345
const valueOfId = getParamFromUrl(url, 'id') //6789

console.log('valueOfCode ' + valueOfCode)
console.log('valueOfId ' + valueOfId)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple function by splitting `url` over `/` to get the value if the value always succeeds the text:

```js
const url = 'http://www.somedomain.com/code/12345/id/6789';

function getValue(text) {
  const arr = url.split('/');
  return arr[arr.indexOf(text) + 1];
}

console.log(['code', 'id'].map(getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const url = 'http://www.somedomain.com/code/12345/id/6789';
const splitString = url.split('/');
console.log('code',splitString[4]);
console.log('id',splitString[6]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url_string = "http://www.somedomain.com/code/12345/id/6789"; 
const url = new URL(url_string);
const tail = url_string.replace(url.origin,""); //→code/12345/id/6789";
const items= tail.split('/').filter(item => item.length > 0); //→["code", "12345", "id", "6789"]
console.log(items.filter(item => items.indexOf(item) % 2 === 1)); //→["12345", "6789"]
```